# Forward fill Pandas df only if an entire line is made of Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to forward fill a pandas df with the previous line only when the current line is entirely composed of`nan`. 
This means that `fillna(method='ffill', limit = 1)` does not work in my case because it works element wise while I would need a `fillna` line wise.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this task than the following instructions?

```
s = df.count(axis = 1)

for d in df.index[1:]:
    if s.loc[d] == 0:
        i = s.index.get_loc(d)
        df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i-1]
```

Input

```
    v1  v2
1    1   2
2  nan   3
3    2   4
4  nan nan
```

Output

```
    v1  v2
1    1   2
2  nan   3
3    2   4
4    2   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditions for filter rows for applying `ffill`:

```
m = df.isnull().all(axis=1) | df.notnull().all(axis=1)
print (m)
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

print (df[m])
    v1   v2
1  1.0  2.0
3  2.0  4.0
4  NaN  NaN

df[m] = df[m].ffill()
print (df)
    v1   v2
1  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
4  2.0  4.0
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
    v1   v2
1  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  8.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  2.0  4.0
6  NaN  3.0
7  NaN  NaN

m = df.isnull().all(axis=1) | df.notnull().all(axis=1)
print (m)
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool

long_str = 'some long helper str'
df[~m] = df[~m].fillna(long_str)
df = df.ffill().replace(long_str, np.nan)

print (df)
    v1   v2
1  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  8.0
4  4.0  8.0
5  2.0  4.0
6  NaN  3.0
7  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: why do you also  specify `df.notnull().all(axis=1)` in the condition for the mask ?

Comment: because else match only `NAN`s rows and ffill cannot work.

Comment: I've just realized that if line 2 and line 3 were switched, the solution you propose would fill line 4 with line 2 and not with line 3.

Comment: You want fill NaN with NaNs? if `2,3` rows are swapped, last row should by `NaN`, `3` ?

Comment: if row 3 is `NAN, 3` and row 4 is `NAN, NAN`, I 'd like to fill row 4 with row 3, even if there is a nan.

Comment: Please check edited answer - need helper varable for replace NaN.